# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9'

Tags: python, unicode

I use python to get json data from bing api

```
    accountKeyEnc = base64.b64encode(accountKey + ':' + accountKey)
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + accountKeyEnc}
    req = urllib2.Request(bingUrl, headers = headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    content = response.read()
    data = json.loads(content)
    for i in range(0,6):
            print data["d"]["results"][i]["Description"]
```

But I got error

> print data["d"]["results"][0]["Description"]
>       UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position        11: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Elizion sorry, I did not get it, how to use...

Comment: What is `accountKey`?

Comment: @Elizion bing's account

Comment: That error indicates that Python does not know what encoding to use for console output - it's assuming the lowest common denominator, which is `'ascii'`. There are *lots* of characters that just don't exist in [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) so you get an error when you try to print them.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are reading Unicode from the Bing API and then failing to explicitly convert it to ASCII. There does not exist a good mapping between the two. Prefix all of your const strings with `u` so that they will be seen as Unicode strings, see if that helps.